# How to show my sidebar in specific page only?

Tags: plugins, sidebar, conditional-content

I would like to show a plugin in a specific page's sidebar only.

**For Example:** 
I have the pages like ..

- home
- about us
- - sub page 1
- - sub page 2
- - sub page 3
- - sub page 4

**UPdate:**

i want to show, **plugin 1** in **sub page 1** and **sub page 4 only** and not to all other pages.i tried `is_page('sub page 1','sub page 4')` but not working :(.please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to [use is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) with multiple pages is as follows:

```
is_page(array(42,'about-me','Contact'));
```

You have to use the `array` keyword

Answer (score 2):

You may try [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin. It let you define via a simple expression like `is_page` or `is_single`, if the widget has to be shown.

Comment: here i can't activate "plugin 1" for    "sub page 1" && "sub page 3" only.how to use?i tried  ->`is_page('sub page 1')&&is_page('sub page 2')`.but it won't show both pages.please help me..

Comment: [view here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-widget-logic-how-to-show-the-widget-in-selected-multiple-pages?replies=1#post-2230862) i posted in wp forum too.

Comment: See the answer of Lea.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Widgets and Widget Logic plugin work at the Widget level. If you are using the Genesis Framework, the Genesis Simple Sidebar plugin let's you create additional sidebars, and designate which pages they appear on.